# Ubuntu 14.04 Shotwell profiles

Tags: ubuntu, printing, tags

I would like to know if I can run Shotwell photo manager within the same ubuntu username with different profiles.

I have a series of photos, pictures and imagery. some of them are personal photos and evidence. Others are scanned material such as documents pages books guides receipts etc.

I would like to separate the personal from information organisation ...so as to have personal photos under one profile and all other stuff under another profile.

I use Shotwell photo manager for its good tagging capabilities and am open to other viable options.

Any android apps that can be used to QR embed my printed paper pages from a Shotwell Photo Manager database and then have them retrieved in that database by scanning the QR code(on the paper page)??
Can I modify Shotwell Photo Manager to automatically print a QR identifier on the reverse on any paper pages printed from within Shotwell Photo Manager??

Please help on this one

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to the first problem (different profiles) ... start shotwell with:

```
$ shotwell --datadir=<datadir>
```

Shotwell will use the supplied directory to hold the database and other assorted files for the library.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/11074